# Javascript inside question

Tags: discussion

what happen if a post the following question in stackoverflow?

```
<script>
alert("javascript");
</script>
```

In other words, does stackoverflow sanitize the question text?

Comment: You could have used the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) for that. It's filtered.

Comment: where is this sandbox?

Answer (score 5):

The question text is sanitized. Only a [(very) small subset of HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909) is tolerated.

`<script>` tags are not included in the whitelist. Only a *very specific* set of attributes are allowed, and only on `<img>` and `<a>` tags. Use attributes anywhere else and the tag is stripped completely.